# How to know the last value of a incremented value

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 0;
xaxis = {
    showLabels: true,
    tickFormatter: function(n) {
        if(n)
        {
            a++;
            alert(a);
        }
    }
}
```

This function is executed 'n' number of times dynamically.
So sometimes the value of `a` comes as 7, 10,... or any number depending upon the selection made by the user.

My question is, is it possible to know the last time iteration of `a` .

For example if `a` was 6 , then I want to use

```
if (a == 6)
  then do something 
else
  do something
```

**You can test this in [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fuNp6/)**

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're after. Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example of this?

Comment: @JohnP: You invalidly formatted my code amendments (missing closing brace, changed colon to equality).

Comment: As far as I know you have to define an extra variable, that contains your last value before you do an increment of the real variable. This one has to get the same scope.
What you can also try is use '++a' instead of 'a++'.

Comment: @reporter: 1) If you need to know the "last value", just doing `a - 1` is better than using an extra variable 2) `++a` vs. `a++` makes no difference here.

Comment: @robert, whoops, apologies. I've rollbacked the changes you made.

Comment: @user663724: does `a` get reset to 0 before you start iterating it using `tickFormatter`?

Answer (score 0):

Just access `a` after all the `tickFormatter` calls have been done. Through the magic of closures it will have the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Store a in another variable before incrementing.

```
if(n)
{
    tmpvariable = a;
    a++;
    alert(a);
}
```

Comment: why not just `a-1`? in that case?

Comment: sure, but user663724's code is very trivial, I don't know what he wants to accomplish :)

Comment: Thanks everybody , what i am after is taht , assume this xaxis { } as a loop and this executed n times , so i want to know the last time , for example if n is 8 then if(n==8)

Comment: @user663724: **Your JSFiddle is incomplete, invalid and doesn't do anything...** We can't really see what you're after? If you want us to help you, you should put some effort into your question and example. The same as you expect from us.

Comment: So what is the problem now? Because you can just access "a" and it will show the last value yes.

Comment: How can i know ?? Assume that the value of a is set dynamically to 7 , how can i compare this as if(a==7) ??

Comment: Write your code in pseudocode because you are not making alot of sense anymore...